# How do I override windows service status perception?

Tags: windows, services

I've got a phantom/ghost service.
The executable is not running. Service Control Manager thinks it's running. Something needs that service to be stopped, it asks Windows ,which will happily continue claiming it's running. (It's not.).

How can I force windows, at a **very low level**, to think it's no longer running? Override what *scm* thinks?

Trying to stop it (via powershell, UI, using the old `net`, or `sc` tool) gets *error 1061* or equivalent. Obviously, you can't communicate with a process that doesn't exist.

Trying to disable/enable it has no effect, it stays as status 'running'.

Trying to stop via `stop-service` gets a funny message about a service that `can't be stopped on computer ''`, obviously there's no computer the program is running on, so it's probably printing the program name of `NULLPTR`.

Comment: What happens if you try "Restart"? This may seem nonsensical, but it's a distinct operation from "Stop" and then "Start".

Comment: Error 1061. 
It appears the windows internals cannot handle a vanishing program.

Comment: Also, yet again: Dear close-voter: Please do enlighten us about what you think is missing from the question.

Comment: (It wasn't me.) Can you include in your post screenshots that show the problem?

Comment: Can you add to the question the output of:
`sc.exe queryex servicename`
and the SCM registry export for the service, i.e. under:  `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\servicename` Thanks.